# Find a three independent vectors u, v, w that each lie in N(A), the null space of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&  4& -4&  4\\
        -1& -2&  2& -2
\end{pmatrix}$

Find a three independent vectors $u, v, w$ that each lie in  $N(A)$, the null space of A. Can someone please explain how I would solve this problem.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Reduce A to RREF and then find a basis for N(A).

Answer (score 1):

We can do this the usual way, apply row operations until we obtain [(reduced) row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) and find a basis of the solution space for $[A|\mathbf{0}]$.  But, in this case, there's a shortcut.

By definition, the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) is the set of vectors $\mathbf{v}$ for which $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, and in cases when columns are multiple of one another, we can find examples of vectors in the null space easily.

E.g. the second column of $A$ is equal to the first column multiplied by $2$.  Hence $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is in the null space.  The same technique works for other pairs of columns (since they're all multiples of one another).  This is enough to give three linearly independent vectors in the null space.